# Does pausing a VM on ESXi release resources?

Tags: vmware-esxi

Does pausing a VM on ESXi release resources?

If I have a vm that is running slow will pausing other VMs help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that will work just fine.

Comment: @NitroxDM - In addition, you may want to look into setting resource reservations for this VM so that it always is able to get the resources it needs.